# Bash Console putting some invisible chars into string var

Tags: string, bash, sed, grep

Below I shared my console. I want to cut some string from output of some commands.
But there are 17 extra chars which I have no idea where comes from. 
Can someone pls explain to me?

```
$ ls -al | grep total | sed 's/[[:blank:]].*$//' | wc -m
      23
$ ns="total"
$ echo $ns | sed 's/[[:blank:]].*$//' | wc -c
       6
```

Comment: Parsing `ls` is never recommended so if you could let us know completed requirement then we could look for option like `find` or something else for same.

Comment: So then you removed the `| wc -m` to examine the actual output and discovered what?

Comment: this was only dummy representation of my problem. 
I was using the output of kubectl command in my bash script and cutting out the first part of it then pass through some other function. and I was not able to display the pods with the same namespace string. There was also no coloring on my shell. 
I used the ls command for making the way more simpler. And it worked.
Thanks all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But there are 17 extra chars which I have no idea where comes from.

Those are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) that `grep` uses for coloring matching substrings. You probably have an alias (run `alias | grep grep` to examine) like

```
alias grep='grep --color=always'
```

somewhere that causes `grep` to color matches even if output is not a tty, or something similar.

Try

```
ls -al | grep --color=never total | sed 's/[[:blank:]].*$//' | wc -m
```

and you'll get six.

Comment: thanks a lot `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'` this what I had in ym bashrc.